# Clear/delete non-default properties of a processor with the NiFi REST API?

Tags: python, python-requests, apache-nifi, nifi-api

I am using requests in python and am sending a PUT request to `https://nifi:<port>/nifi-api/processors/{my-processor-id}`, where `pid` is the id of the processor to be modified:

```
modify = requests.put(f"{nifi_api_url}/processors/{pid}", proxies=proxies, headers=headers, json=json_data, verify=False)
```

For `json_data` (which is the `ProcessorEntity`) I am passing in the following:

```
json_data = {
        "revision": {
            "version": revision_version
        }, 
        "component": {
            "id": pid,
            "config": {
                "properties": None
            }
        }
    }
```

(I have also tried passing in `properties: {}` to no avail.)

Passing in both `None` and `{}` do not delete any properties for some reason, whereas adding properties via the API works perfectly fine using this endpoint.

Comment: what is the problem/question?

Comment: The problem is that passing in `None` or `{}` as the value to `properties` when sending a PUT request to the NiFi API does not actually clear or delete any `properties`

Comment: do what you want from browser (nifi-ui), trace an api call in devtools/network, and then just reproduce it from your code.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure out the issue by doing this